# Makefile reporting multiple definition of `func[abi:cxx11]()'

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, linker-errors

My professor wants us to use terminal to compile and run some c++ code before we use an IDE and I'm having some trouble creating the Makefile for it. I went to his office for help today but he was very vague with his answers. I've been looking around online and found a video that is helpful, but I've encountered an error I don't know how to fix

I tried editing the Makefile in a text editor using:

```
all:
    g++ main.cpp myfunc.cpp -o myexe
```

Then I went into the terminal window and typed:

```
$ make
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
g++ main.cpp myfunc.cpp -o myexe
/tmp/ccjSAvna.o: In function `func[abi:cxx11]()':
myfunc.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `func[abi:cxx11]()'
/tmp/cczKi1CW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I'm not really sure what this error message means or how I can go about fixing my problem.

Comment: Sounds like you just defined two functions both named `func()`. Rename one of them.

Comment: That was my error, thank you.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with `main.cpp` and `myfunc.cpp`. Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not really sure what this error message means [...]

It's reasonably straight-forward once you realize where each line comes from. The first line is the command produced by `make` from your makefile:

> ```
> g++ main.cpp myfunc.cpp -o myexe
> ```

It's a little strange, but functional. Usually a makefile will compile each source file individually, then link the resulting object files together, but doing everything in one step is possible.

The next couple of lines are the output of `g++`:

> ```
> /tmp/ccjSAvna.o: In function `func[abi:cxx11]()':
> myfunc.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `func[abi:cxx11]()'
> /tmp/cczKi1CW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
> ```

These indicate a bug in your code. Since this has nothing to do with your makefile, I'll move on to the next lines.

> ```
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

This line just shows the result of the command from earlier. This is what one should expect to see after a linker error.

> ```
> Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 1
> ```

These lines are diagnostics from `make` telling you when your build failed. It failed when trying to run the command you defined for "all". It's a bit superfluous in this case, but when you deal with more complex makefiles, knowing which rule failed can be a timesaver.

> [...] or how I can go about fixing my problem.

You'll probably want to debug your code before looking for issues in your makefile.